# an added value of array of request disappears in Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel

the user id is existed Before doing create. so it causes an error in the first one.
I made it the other way. the second one below works correctly.
I would like to know why the first one is wrong and it's gone.

```
//Error
    public function store(ContactRequest $request)
    {
        $request->user_id = $request->user()->id;
        Log::debug($request->user()->id);
        Log::debug($request);
        Contact::create($request->all());
    }
```

//OK

```
    public function store(ContactRequest $request,Contact $contact)
    {

        $request->user_id = $request->user()->id;

        $contact->title = $request->title;
        $contact->body = $request->body;
        $contact->user_id = $request->user()->id;
        $contact->save();
    }
```

```
the log of the first one is here.
What happened to the user_id!?
```

```
[2020-05-30 15:59:10] local.DEBUG: 59  
[2020-05-30 15:59:10] local.DEBUG: array (
  '_token' => 'gGWuxW6C2JRSCYDuCAC9HauynGclKQEQB7qUh6Rw',
  'title' => 'TITLE',
  'body' => 'MESSAGE',
  'action' => 'SEND',
)
```

Contact is model class.
ContactRequest is here.

```
class ContactRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|max:100',
            'body' => 'required|max:1000'
        ];
    }
    public function attributes() {
        return [
            'title' => 'title',
            'body' => 'CONTENTS'
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `$request->merge(['user_id'=>$request->user()->id])`.
 Another tips is that you can simply use `Auth::user()->id` which also return the user id of current user.

Answer (score 1):

What if you do this:

```
Auth::user() - >contact($request->all()) - >save() ;
```

Or also as an experiment:

```
$contact = new Contact($request->all()) ;
$contact->user_id = Auth::user() - >id;
$contact->save() ;
```

Actually the second snippet will surely work. The first one I did not test though it looks nice. :)